# What is the value of the string @""?

Tags: objective-c, string, text, nsstring, uitextfield

I'm writing an iPhone application that uses a lot of editable text fields. I've been learning a lot about UITextFields and NSStrings by reading various references online, but there are some details that still elude me. When a user puts in an incorrect value for one of my text fields, I throw up an error message and put the text field back to the way it was before their input. For empty text fields, I've been doing this:

```
theTextField.text = @"";
```

Is this the best way to do this? I just came up with the idea myself, I don't know if there are any problems with it (other than the fact that it seems to work just fine so far).

Also, does @"" have the same value as a "nil" string? In other words, if I set a string to @"" and then call this:

```
if (myString) {...}
```

will the statement return true or false?

One last thing. When an NSString is initialized using this:

```
NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

what is that string's **Length** value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using

```
theTextField.text = @"";
```

is absolutely ok. There should be no problems at all.

```
if (@"")
```

will evaluate to true. `@""` is not the same as nil.

The length of

```
NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

is 0.

Comment: `@""`, like any other NSString literals, is a constant instance of NSString. It has its own memory space where it spends the application's lifetime in, and is not autoreleased. (Also, this is a very pedantic comment.)

Comment: @BoltClock, no it's not pedantic, thanks. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks, these will be very helpful things to know!

Answer (score 3):

The important thing to understand here is that an `NSString` with no characters in it, such as `@""` or `[[NSString alloc] init]` is still a valid object. All the consequences that Nick has stated follow from that.

In Objective-C, any valid object will be "True" in a boolean context;* `nil` is the only false object value.

Since these strings are valid objects, they do have a length, but because they contain no characters, the length is 0.

There are no problems with assigning an empty string object `@""` to another string pointer, such as the `text` of your text field. Since the string with no characters is still a valid `NSString` object, this is exactly the same as assigning a string which *does* happen to have characters.

---

<sub>*Unlike so-called "scripting" languages like Python or Perl, where an empty string or collection evaluates to boolean false.</sub>

Comment: Okay, that's what I was trying to figure out-- the difference between an empty String and a nil String is like the difference between 0 and null.

Comment: @Poaters: Not quite -- in C and ObjC, `O` and `NULL` are equivalent. If you've done Python, `nil` and `None` are pretty close in meaning, though not effect. I think `undef` is the corresponding entity in Perl.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer to the question, but may be the answer to what you're trying to do.
If you're wondering whether you have to write `if(str && str.length)` to cover both `nil` and empty strings, you don't. You may use just `if(str.length)`, since, in Objective-C, unknown messages to `nil` will return `nil` (so `[a.b.c.d.e.f doStuff]` will be `nil` if any of those values in the chain is `nil`). There is thus scarce need for specific nullity checks, unless what you want is precisely to determine nullity.

Answer (score 0):

Check `NSString`'s [`+ string`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/string).